# MapHolding action on MapControl doesn't work... a workaround?

Tags: c#, events, uwp, maps, uwp-maps

It seems that holding method does not work since 2015:
[Win10 App - Holding & Releasing the map to manipulate an element on the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870330/win10-app-holding-releasing-the-map-to-manipulate-an-element-on-the-interfac)

or simply I don't know how to use it, anyway I need to manage a user holding on PC or mobile of a map.

My map is like a navigator, it follows the user position while it is moving, but when user use gesture to see the map around I have to stop the .center position of the user pushpin.

But I cannot find a way to understand when user move the map. The docs tell to use the holding event
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps

but I've tried it on PC and my app doesnt enter in the holding event.

I've tried all the other events, only maptapped and actualcamerachanged works. 
but I don't know how to difference from a user move or a map .center move from the app.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with a little of WinMerge and some try

you can find the FocusState.Pointer in sender when the user try to move the map, if not with the map.center you get a FocusState.Unfocused by the sender

```
private void Mappe_ActualCameraChanged(MapControl sender, MapActualCameraChangedEventArgs args)
         {
            if (sender.FocusState == FocusState.Pointer)
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

MapHolding doesn't fire immediately on Pointer down. It fires on a press and long hold after a delay, and only if the map isn't moved. It's intended for things like displaying a context menu (like right-click).
The MapActualCameraChangingEventArgs for the ActualCameraChanging event should tell you if the map moved due to user interaction or due to being changed programmatically.